# General coordinate transfomation

Tags: coordinate-transformation, differential-geometry

I am looking for a (free) package or snippet that makes the transformation of tensors between spacetimes easy. What do you suggest?

Comment: I think it'd be nice to have some more context for the kind of things you are trying to do. An example of what you would like this package to do would be good.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. An example of such transformations is given in my paper:
 https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FJHEP11%282018%29181.pdf
Please see Eq. 6.10. This is a transformation between two spacetimes, and part of it is a coordinate transformation.

Comment: Because I (among many others) am very lazy, can you write up an explicit example of what you're trying to do and provide a concrete example with psuedo-code for what you'd like to happen? I (and many others) would prefer that to having to dig through the paper and figure out the necessary context.